# Center content of two side-by-side divs vertically no matter what size content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out a way to vertically center the content of two side-by-side divs when there is an image on the left, and text on the right. The only problem is, that it has to work even if the length of the paragraph changes. Is there a way to ensure that the image/paragraph in each "section" are always centered vertically, regardless of if the image height is larger or smaller than the paragraph text height?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <p>
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <p>
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet 
       Lorem ipsum delor sit amet Lorem ipsum delor sit amet
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section {
  padding: 1% 0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 25%;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
img, p {
  float: left;
  padding: 2% 1%;
}
```

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fLgsrqqm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this rule: (no float, vertical-align: middle)

```
img, p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2% 1%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3wt1t8zx/

Answer (score 1):

Add below code and see if it works:

```
.paragraph {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS3 Flexbox to do the layout:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also have a look at:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox